# Radio not serializing with serializeArray

Tags: php, jquery, html, serialization

index.php:

```
<form id = "regform" action = "registration.php" method = "POST">
    <label id = "namelabel">Username: </label> <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "username" maxlength = "40" placeholder = "Enter a Username"><br>
    <label id = "namelabel">Password: </label> <input type = "password" class = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "Enter Password"><br>
    <label id = "namelabel">Gender: </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "Male"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "Female"> Female
    <label id = "namelabel">Email: </label> <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "email" placeholder = "Enter your Email"><br>
    <a href="#" title="Register" id = "register" style = "margin-left:25px;">Register</a>
</form>

$("#register").click(function () {
    $.post($('#regform').attr("action"), $('#regform').serializeArray(), function (data) {
        if (data == 'checkradio') {
            $('#regmsg').html('Please choose a gender.');
        }
    });
});
```

Server side:

```
$required_fields = array('username','password','gender','email');
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value) {
    if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true){
        echo 'checkradio';
    }
}
```

It serializes everything except the Radio buttons. What is the problem?

Comment: That happens when Radio button is not checked.

Answer (score 6):

As @undefined told you, unchecked checkboxes and radios are not sent.

If you don't want a default checked state for your gender field, then add a hidden input field with the same name and empty value before the radios:

```
<input type="hidden" name="gender" value="" />
```

Forms are processed sequentially, so if the radio is checked, its value will override the hidden input value

Comment: This creates another input that is not part of the radio group. When re-using the form with previous entries, this will behave wrong. @Purple Tentacle answer works better as it will keep the input in the same group than the other visible radio buttons.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="" style="display:none;" checked>
```

Add an extra radio option like this, the value will be nothing and it will not show to the user.

Updated to add 'checked' as suggested by @Larzan. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add the checked, otherwise this would be the same as the other radio buttons: not showing up.
So the full line would be:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="" style="display:none;" checked>

Answer (score 0):

Unselected select control and unchecked checkbox or radio button control will never be posted, unless you change type to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In your case require add 'checked' attribute to one radio-button for pre-select one as default. This information from [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and from HTML specification(linked from [jQuery documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
$("#register").click(function(event){
  if($("#regform").find("input[name='gender']").is(':checked')){
    $("#regform").submit()
  } else {
    alert("Choose the gender!");
  }

  event.preventDefault();
})
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

It's very surprising to me that no one yet mentioned the proper way of doing this. If you use a form, then you should use the `submit` event and then you can easily use the `serializeArray` function.

Here's an example:

```
$( "#magic-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    console.log($(this).serializeArray());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This give you a beautiful array with all your values including the radio box.

Example output

```
{
    {name: "company", value: "asd"}
    {name: "name", value: "asd"}
    {name: "email", value: "sad@web.de"}
    {name: "phone", value: ""}
    {name: "radio-group", value: "value3"}
    {name: "terms", value: "on"}
}
```

Comment: It's a reasonable point, but it's not what the OP asked help with, which was that radio buttons are not sent with the serialiseArray() method.